# Talend Execute with parameter in Shell

Tags: parameters, talend

I am trying to execute in Shell a Talend Job with parameter = current_date.
When the date is hard coded it works :

- FACT_TALEND_run.sh --context_param DATE='2022-04-16 00:00:00'

When i try to use a variable, it does not work

- FACT_TALEND_run.sh --context_param DATE='current_date'

Comment: did you try using : $(date +%F_%H %M-%S)

Comment: What is this "current_date" variable? if you want to pass the system date as a parameter, try what Amine suggested: FACT_TALEND_run.sh --context_param DATE=$(date +%F_%H %M-%S)